# How to justify whole text in Rmd with bookdown::gitbook as output

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, bookdown, gitbook

I would like to justify all the text in my gitbook, but I couldn't find a solution. So far I've tried:

- Set the text-align as justified in the style/body, right after the YAML Header:

  `<style>
  body {
    text-align: justify
  }
  </style>`

It doesn't work.

- Set the text-align as justified in div tag for the whole text:

  `<div style="text-align:justify;">
  my whole text
  </div>`

It works, but the numbering of the topics are lost (probably with other features I didn't figure out).

The thing is, I don't want to lose any standard feature of the output from bookdown::gitbook but the "text-align" (which I want it to be justified).

Also, it would be too much work to have to put a div tag in all the sentences. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pity this didnt get an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your CSS code in a css file, say, `custom.css`:

```css
body {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Then include it via the `css` option (I don't know what you meant by "preamble" in your post; if it meant the LaTeX preamble, it would be the wrong place to put CSS):

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: "custom.css"
```

If it doesn't work (I have tested it and it works for me), please provide a reproducible example, and ideally also a published (web) version of your example, so we can easily investigate your CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Yihui Xie! It works!

About the "preamble", I made a mistake. What I actually meant is "YAML header". I've edited that info in the post. Thank you again, and congrats for your work! Best!